# Saving Canvas to device memory in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, canvas, xamarin.forms, save

I have canvas made from bitMap (photo) and my finger drawings in Xamarin Forms. I need to save it to memory device (perfectly it would be photo roll but could be just memory of device). For now (after googling few hours) i have something like this:

```
saveButt.Clicked += async(sender, args) =>
{
    var newSurface = SKSurface.Create(
        (int)canvasView.CanvasSize.Width,
        (int)canvasView.CanvasSize.Height,
        SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType,
        SKAlphaType.Premul);

    var canvas = newSurface.Canvas;
    if (photoBitmap != null)
    {
        canvas.DrawBitmap(photoBitmap, new SKRect(0, 0, (float) canvasView.Width, (float) canvasView.Height));
    }

    foreach (SKPath path in completedPaths)
    {
        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
    }

    foreach (SKPath path in inProgressPaths.Values)
    {
        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
    }

    canvas.Flush();
    var snap = newSurface.Snapshot();
    var pngImage = snap.Encode();
};
```

I don't know how i can get access to memory or photo roll to save it.

@Edit
I tried use PCLStorage plugin to save it and for now it don't throw any exceptions or errors but still when i look through all folders i can't find any new folder or file with those names.

```
            var snap = newSurface.Snapshot();
            var pngImage = snap.Encode();
            IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
            IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MySubFolder",
                CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("image.png",
                CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (Stream s = await file.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
            {
                pngImage.SaveTo(s);
            }
```

Comment: You already have it in memory, you've stored it in `pngImage`.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I don't have it anywhere in my phone files as i checked. I would like to save it to any folder on my phone like i have screenshots, gallery, discord images etc.

Comment: Convert your image to `Stream` and save it using `File.IO`. On Android you will have to get MediaScanner to run to have it appear in the gallery.

Comment: I added code i wrote for saving it in PCLStorage @Cheesebaron but it still is not saving (or is saving and i just can't find it). I don't know, should i check any permissions ?